# how to pass array with xmlhttp.open method through php file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is the code

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get" >
      <input type="text" id="jk" name="jk" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="jk2" name="jk" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="jk3" name="jk3" style="width:100%; height:200px;" />
      <br />
      <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="submit" onClick="showvalue()" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my java script

```
function showvalue() {
  var a=document.getElementById("jk").value;
  var b =document.getElementById("jk2").value;
  var arr = new Array(a,b);
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {     
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)     {       
      document.getElementById("jk3").value=xmlhttp.responseText;    
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","testphp.php?q="+arr,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

this is my testphp file

```php
<?php 
  $arr = array();
  $arr = $_REQUEST["q"];

  echo $arr[0];
?>
```

When i use this code result incorrect. I need to show sent array one element. How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the lines as follow

Javascript:

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","testphp.php?q="+arr,true)  
             to
  xmlhttp.open("GET","testphp.php?q="+ JSON.stringify(arr),true);
```

PHP:

```
 $arr = $_REQUEST["q"]; 
       to 
 $arr = $_REQUEST["q"];
 $arr = json_decode($arr);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate arrays and strings in JS like you tried.
You can make query string with loop and then add it to the URL:

```
var query = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {
    query += '&';
  } // if
  query += 'q[' + i + ']=' + arr[i];
} // for
var url = 'testphp.php?' + query;
```